# Issue with HSET command in Rust Redis

Tags: rust, redis

I am currently trying to convert the following Redis command into rust:

```
HSET book_store_list 1 1,2,3
```

Essentially, create the bookstore_list Hash, with a Field (1) and value (1,2,3) which works fine within the Redis GUI.

The issue is that the hset API in rust redis does not seem to work as I envisioned.

For example:

```
let vector = vec![1,2,3]
hset("book_store_list", 1, &vector)
```

Results in two Field-Value entries within the book_store_list hash

Field 1 Value 1
Field 2 Value 3

The issue is that the redis rust crate seems to interpret the [1,2,3] vector to be separate values (with 2 and 3 being a new field value pair) to be cached in instead of one value. Just wondering if anyone has faced this issue before?

Comment: `redis-rs` maintainer here. The library's handling of your request here is regrettable. Rather than setting multiple fields, we should disallow this at compile time. If you want to open an issue [here](https://github.com/redis-rs/redis-rs/issues), that would be awesome.

Your other problem is that Redis doesn't support natively setting list types as values for hash fields. The value you're setting in your first example is interpreted as a string literal with the value "1,2,3". If this is ok with you, you could first serialize the Vec in Rust as a string with this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe that I have found the answer. In order for Redis to accept [1,2,3] as one singular value, we must call the `to_string` api from the `serde_json` crate like so:

```
let value = serde_json::to_string(&vector).unwrap();
```

I guess the lesson of this is to stringify all values before invoking any HSET commands in rust redis!